# Формальная и фактические функции в С++

Tags: c++

Что подразумевают под понятиями формальной и фактической функции, и где они применяются?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вы имеете введу формальные и фактические параметры?
Если да, то:
Формальные параметры - это те, которые вы пишите в прототипе функции.
Фактические - те, которые вы передаете при вызове функции.

Comment: Не совсем, далее спрашивается где описываются формальные параметры формальной вункции? Именно это и ставит в тупик.

Comment: В объявлении (т.е. прототипе), видимо =D

Comment: а можна пример.

Comment: <pre>int printf ( const char * format, ... );</pre>
Это прототип из заговолочного файла. format - это формальный аргумент.
А в коде мы напишем:
<pre>printf("blablabla");<pre>
так вот: "blablabla" - это фактический аргумент.

Comment: Объявление и прототип - немного разные вещи (ну это к слову). А речь о чём? Об этом:
 
    float intrigal(float  a, float b, float d, float f(float )) {
 float s = 0, x;
 for(x = a; fabs(x - b) > d; x += d) s += f(x);
 return s * d;
    }

Comment: Вот @alexiz формально (а по сути верно) подошел к заданному вопросу, продемонстрировав это в своем примере. Очевидно, в описании intrigal(... float f(float)), f - формальный параметр (указатель на функцию). Он (видимо) был фактическим при вызове intrigal(), в s += f(x); надо понимать остался формальным. А если внутри intrigal() вызвать printf ("%f ",f(x)); - то в этом месте f станет называться фактическим ?

Comment: >то в этом месте f станет называться фактическим ?
он станет фактическим по отношению к printf, но по отношению к intrigal - формальным.

Comment: Всем спасибо ребята, очень помогли.

Comment: Хоть вопрос и закрыт, но маленькое добавление. В `printf ("%f", f(x))` f не является никаким параметром. Там речь может идти только о значении `f(x)`